# Issues using strip() on a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitch, urllib3

I'm trying to strip the characters `b,'()`.
The issue I'm having is that it says TypeError 'str' does not support the buffer interface.

Here are the relevant parts of code in this:

```
import urllib3
def command_uptime():

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://nightdev.com/hosted/uptime.php?channel=TrippedNW')
    rawData = r.data
    liveTime = bytes(rawData.strip("b,\'()", rawData))

    message = "Tripped has been live for: ", liveTime
    send_message(CHAN, message)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. Its not clear which lines are in your function and which aren't

Comment: you have `.split()` in your code not `.strip()`

Comment: Fixing right now @PaulRooney

Comment: I guess its actually pretty clear that all of its in the function :)

Comment: Either way, I still get the same error @JoeR

Comment: `rawData` is a `bytes` object, so trying to strip `str`s from it wouldn't work. Change `"b,\'()"` to `b"b,\'()"` (the `b` in front makes it a bytes literal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is binary data. Its not a string. You need to decode it first.

Also you don't need to pass `rawData` to itself in strip method.

```
import urllib3

def command_uptime():

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://nightdev.com/hosted/uptime.php?channel=TrippedNW')
    strData = r.data.decode('utf-8')
    liveTime = strData.strip("b,\'()")

    message = "Tripped has been live for: %s" % liveTime
    print(message)

command_uptime()
```

Be also aware that your `message` variable is a tuple not a string. I dont know if `send_message` expects this. I formatted it into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the second argument.

```
import urllib3
def command_uptime():

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://nightdev.com/hosted/uptime.php?channel=TrippedNW')
    rawData = r.data
    liveTime = bytes(rawData.strip("b,'()"))

    print("Tripped has been live for: %s" % liveTime)


command_uptime()
```

Output:

```
Tripped has been live for:  1 hour, 18 minutes
```